# Rails validation not running when creating new associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a custom validation that makes sure I don't have too many associations in a HABTM association. Here is the validation in the `Request` model

```
  validate :max_tags

  MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_OF_TAGS = 5

  def max_tags
    debugger
    unless tags.count < MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_OF_TAGS
       errors[:base ] << "You cannot have more than #{MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_OF_TAGS} tags on this gift request." 
    end
  end
```

This validation runs whenever I create a new `Request`; however, it isn't executed whenever I create `tags` and associate it to the `Request`. Here is a block of code where the validation doesn't execute when create new associations

```
if @request.save
  if tags
    tags.each do |tag|
      tag = Tag.find_by_name(tag)
      if tag
        self.tags << tag
        tag.increment_gift_request_count
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you said that you're using habtm.  in that case, according to the docs, `<<` instantly fires an sql update so no validation is ran in the parent object.

Answer (score 1):

You may validate number tags with **before_add** callback, like this:

```
MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_OF_TAGS = 5
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, before_add: :validate_max_tags

private

def validate_max_tags(tag)
  if (tags.count > MAXIMUM_AMOUNT_OF_TAGS) 
    errors.add(:base, :max_tag_error)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

Comment: Me and a mate spent two days trying to do exactly this. Thanks a ton.